# Dash app doesn't show plot based on dropdown selection

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

Iam trying to plot simple medical data on dash app  and this data has hospital names columns. Now what I want is to have a dropdown of hospitals in that when someone selects a hospitals, Its data gets ploted. Here is the app but its failing

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# intialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital','Nick hospital', 'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital','Krish hospital'],
        'NAR_forms_used':[2, 1,2, 2, 2,3]
       }

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data

hosp_list = df["Name"].unique()

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
                id="Hosp_list",
                options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in hosp_list],
                multi=True,
                value=list(),

        )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('Hosp_list', 'value')])
def update_figure(Hosp_list):
    # get counts per NAR type
    df_nar=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Name')['NAR_forms_used'].value_counts())
    df_nar=df_nar.rename({'NAR_forms_used': 'Doc count'}, axis='columns')
    df_nar=df_nar.reset_index()

    # Manage NAR types (who knows, there may be more types with time?)
    nars = df_nar['NAR_forms_used'].unique()
    nars = nars.tolist()
    nars.sort(reverse=False)

    # set up plotly figure
    fig = go.Figure()

    # add one trace per NAR type and show counts per hospital
    for nar in nars:

        # subset dataframe by NAR type
        df_ply=df_nar[df_nar['NAR_forms_used']==nar]

        # add trace
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df_ply['Name'], y=df_ply['NAR count'], name='NAR Type='+str(nar)))

        # make the figure a bit more presentable

        fig.update_layout(title='NAR per hospital',
                  yaxis=dict(title='<i>count of NAR types</i>'),
                  xaxis=dict(title='<i>Hospital</i>',
                            )
                 )


    fig.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Kindly help me to fix the app so that it can run. End product is an app where graphs appear based on hospital selection on dropdown

Comment: at the end of the update_figure, add  return fig

Comment: What error are you getting ?